# i m trying to add dataframe into another dataframe with header

Tags: r

I have two data frame which i like to merge in the below mentioned output. I appreciate if someone can show me right path:

**a. Dataframe1**

```
Col1     Col2     Col
zbo      123      40
zbo      6547     50
zbo      6589     60
```

**b. Dataframe2**

```
Column  Column
tile    zbo
file    abc
date    01/09/2018
```

**Expected Result**

```
tile :  zbo
file :  abc
date :  01/09/2018
Col1     Col2     Col
zbo      123      40
zbo      6547     50
zbo      6589     60
```

Comment: sorry i was not clear they are just two columns int he dataframe

Answer (score 1):

We can capture the output of the second dataframe and `paste` with the first one

```
v1 <- do.call(paste, c(df2, sep=" : ", collapse="\n"))
cat(paste(v1, paste(trimws(sub("^\\d+", "", capture.output(df1))),
              collapse="\n"), sep="\n"), sep="\n")
#tile : zbo
#file : abc
#date : 01/09/2018
#Col1 Col2 Col
#zbo  123  40
#zbo 6547  50
#zbo 6589  60
```

---

If we need a one column data.frame as output, remove the `cat` wrapping and use `read.csv` to read it a data.frame

```
read.csv(text = paste(v1, paste(trimws(sub("^\\d+", "", capture.output(df1))),
              collapse="\n"), sep="\n"), header = FALSE)
#                 V1
#1        tile : zbo
#2        file : abc
#3 date : 01/09/2018
#4     Col1 Col2 Col
#5      zbo  123  40
#6      zbo 6547  50
#7      zbo 6589  60
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("zbo", "zbo", "zbo"), Col2 = c(123L, 
 6547L, 6589L), Col = c(40L, 50L, 60L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(Column = c("tile", "file", "date"), Column.1 = c("zbo", 
 "abc", "01/09/2018")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -3L))
```

Comment: some how i m getting result as one column. I like to keep the columns intact. Am i missing something ?

Comment: @gurtej  Yes, in the first dataset, you have 3 columns and in the second, there is 2 columns.  So, I am not sure how the expected output columns would look like

Comment: I just want to put second data set with 2 columns on top of first dataset. and like to have output  in separate columns

Comment: Ok, in that case, you need `library(dplyr);bind_rows(df2, setNames(rbind(colnames(df1), df1), c(names(df2), 'Col')))`